# Retrieve Hosted Content from iTunes(PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

Is there any library designed for PhoneGap to retrieve Hosted Content data from iTunes (In-App purchase)? I was trying InAppPurchaseManager without any luck, maybe is not sufficient for my purposes. Thanks

Comment: Are there any specific problems with InAppPurchaseManager? I have a hard time seeing how anyone can reliably recommend a library when they have no idea what your usage requirements are.

Comment: Specific problem is that I don't know (could not find) a way how to get In-App Purchase package, maybe this feature is not there yet. In my case I have data uploaded as a package to iTunnes.